# AWS signing request micropython

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-signature, esp32, micropython, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Iam running a project on esp32-s3 using micropython.
Iam trying to post logs to aws cloudwatch using https, where it requires me to create an aws v4 signature, however iam getting the following error from AWS:

```
{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

Below is my signing method:

```
try:
    from uhashlib import sha256 as _sha256
except ImportError:
    print("Warning: not using uhashlib")
    from hashlib import sha256 as _sha256

import hmac_ltd as _hmac
import ubinascii as _ubinascii


def request_gen(
    access_key,
    secret_key,
    date_time_stamp,
    method="POST",
    region="us-east-1",
    body="",
    uri="",
):
    service = "logs"
    request_type = "aws4_request"
    algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"


    date_stamp = date_time_stamp[:8]

    return_dict = {}
    return_dict["host"] = f"{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com"
    return_dict["uri"] = "/"


    key = bytearray()
    key.extend(("AWS4" + secret_key).encode())
    print("key: ", key)
    kDate = _hmac.new(key, date_stamp, _sha256).digest()
    kRegion = _hmac.new(kDate, region, _sha256).digest()
    kService = _hmac.new(kRegion, service, _sha256).digest()
    kSigning = _hmac.new(kService, request_type, _sha256).digest()

    content_length = str(len(body))
    print(body)
    payload_hash = _ubinascii.hexlify(_sha256(body.encode("utf-8")).digest()).decode(
        "utf-8"
    )

    # make the string to sign
    canonical_querystring = ""  # no request params for logs

    canonical_headers_dict = {
        "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
        "host": return_dict["host"],
        "x-amz-content-sha256": payload_hash,
        "x-amz-date": date_time_stamp,
        "x-amz-target": "Logs_20140328.PutLogEvents",
    }
    # Build the canonical headers string
    canonical_headers = "\n".join(
        f"{key}:{value}" for key, value in canonical_headers_dict.items()
    )
    # Get the sorted keys for signed_headers
    signed_headers = ";".join(
        sorted(key.lower() for key in canonical_headers_dict.keys())
    )

    canonical_request = (
        method
        + "\n"
        + return_dict["uri"]
        + "\n"
        + canonical_querystring
        + "\n"
        + canonical_headers
        + "\n"
        + signed_headers
        + "\n"
        + payload_hash
    )


    canonical_request_hash = _ubinascii.hexlify(
        _sha256(canonical_request.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    ).decode("utf-8")


    credential_scope = date_stamp + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/" + request_type
    string_to_sign = (
        algorithm
        + "\n"
        + date_time_stamp
        + "\n"
        + credential_scope
        + "\n"
        + canonical_request_hash
    )

    # generate the signature:
    signature = _hmac.new(kSigning, string_to_sign, _sha256).digest()
    signatureHex = _ubinascii.hexlify(signature).decode("utf-8")

    authorization_header = (
        algorithm
        + " "
        + "Credential="
        + access_key
        + "/"
        + credential_scope
        + ", "
        + "SignedHeaders="
        + signed_headers
        + ", "
        + "Signature="
        + signatureHex
    )

    return_dict["headers"] = {
        "authorization": authorization_header,
        "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
        "host": return_dict["host"],
        "x-amz-content-sha256": payload_hash,
        "x-amz-date": date_time_stamp,
        "x-amz-target": "Logs_20140328.PutLogEvents",
    }

    return return_dict
```

Below is my output:

```
##########################################
canonical_request: 
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-target:Logs_20140328.PutLogEvents
x-amz-content-sha256:7dbe84657fbd1885f46b4d0d51a6b49be58c78db693af0fe85e335f28f6efefd
x-amz-date:20231125T183032Z
content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
7dbe84657fbd1885f46b4d0d51a6b49be58c78db693af0fe85e335f28f6efefd
##########################################


string_to_sign: 
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20231125T183032Z
20231125/us-east-1/logs/aws4_request
62143e2e37c17f0122bfce2333c7523c78844be83a23df9c426ddf9109ee8584



signature: 
07685ab92b73a08ca828948e05251296f3a0bdc774f0bc904e8311064e8fc407
##########################################


BEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Request URL = https://logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Request Headers = {"authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<ACCESS_KEY>/20231125/us-east-1/logs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=07685ab92b73a08ca828948e05251296f3a0bdc774f0bc904e8311064e8fc407", "x-amz-date": "20231125T183032Z", "x-amz-target": "Logs_20140328.PutLogEvents", "host": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "x-amz-content-sha256": "7dbe84657fbd1885f46b4d0d51a6b49be58c78db693af0fe85e335f28f6efefd", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1"}


Request payload = {"logGroupName":"esp32-test","logEvents":[{"message":"This is a sample log message from esp32","timestamp":1700937032000}],"logStreamName":"esp32-test-stream-3"}

RESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Response code: 400

{'_content_consumed': False, 'raw': <SSLSocket>, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'reason': b'Bad Request', '_cached': None, 'status_code': 400}
{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
>>>
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Things I tried:

- I made sure system time is correct
- I made sure all hashing methods are correct and compared with online tools
- I followed this guide step by step : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Pi Pico W and using AWS from micropython seems incredibly hard. However, I think I've got it working, and your code was helpful along the way. Getting an exact match for what AWS expects is difficult due to the unavailability of standard libraries. But it's possible. And worth it, because using a microcontroller as a client with the power of AWS on-tap opens up a lot of possibilities?

I'm not sure what hmac_ltd is, but I used

```
import hmac
```

I needed to change line 20 in hmac.py, meaning I couldn't use hmac.mpy (https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-stdlib/hmac/hmac.py)

**/lib/hmac.py**

```
# make_hash = lambda d=b"": hashlib.new(digestmod, d)  # this way does not work with hashlib on micropython
make_hash = lambda d=b"": getattr(hashlib, digestmod)(d) # this way works with hashlib on micropython
```

Here's my code that works to sign an AWS v4 request.

I'm using it to call GET on an AWS lambda function ('execute-api') and you want to POST to a logging function, but I think you can adapt it.

**main.py**

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import ubinascii
import utime
import urequests
import json
import config
import credentials

def getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + secret_key).encode('utf-8'), date_stamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

def create_signed_headers(
    api_host,
    api_uri,
    region,
    service,
    access_key,
    secret_key,
    http_method='GET',
    query_string='',
    additional_headers=None,
    payload=''
):
    # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    t = utime.gmtime()
    amz_date = f"{t[0]:04d}{t[1]:02d}{t[2]:02d}T{t[3]:02d}{t[4]:02d}{t[5]:02d}Z"
    date_stamp = f"{t[0]:04d}{t[1]:02d}{t[2]:02d}"

    # Prepare canonical request
    canonical_querystring = query_string
    canonical_headers = 'host:' + api_host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n'
    signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'
    payload = '' # GET requests don't usually have a payload
    payload_hash = ubinascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(payload.encode('utf-8')).digest()).decode()

    # print(f"\npayload_hash: {payload_hash}\n")
    
    canonical_request = (
        http_method + '\n' + api_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' +
        canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
    )

    # Prepare string to sign
    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
    string_to_sign = (
        algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +
        ubinascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).digest()).decode()
    )

    # Calculate the signature
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service)
    signature = hmac.new(
        signing_key, string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod='sha256'
    ).hexdigest()

    # Prepare authorization header
    authorization_header = (
        algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +
        'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
    )

    # Prepare headers
    headers = {'x-amz-date':amz_date, 'Authorization':authorization_header}
    
    if additional_headers is not None:
        headers.update(additional_headers)

    print("================================")
    print("Canonical Request")
    print("================================")
    print(http_method) # HTTPRequestMethod
    print(api_uri) # CanonicalURI
    print(canonical_querystring) # CanonicalQueryString
    print(canonical_headers) # CanonicalHeaders
    print(signed_headers) # SignedHeaders
    print(payload_hash) # HashedPayload
    print("================================")
    print("String-to-sign")
    print("================================")
    print(string_to_sign)

    return headers

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), digestmod='sha256').digest()

def main():
    additional_headers = {'x-apikey': credentials.RAILDATAORG_API_KEY}
    payload = ""
    http_method = "GET"

    headers = create_signed_headers(
        api_host=config.AWS_API_HOST,
        api_uri=config.AWS_API_URI,
        region=config.AWS_API_REGION,
        service=config.AWS_API_SERVICE, 
        access_key=credentials.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secret_key=credentials.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        query_string=config.AWS_API_QUERYSTRING,
        additional_headers=additional_headers,
        http_method=http_method,
        payload=payload
    )

    try:
        if http_method == 'GET':
            response = urequests.get(config.AWS_API_URL, headers=headers)
        elif http_method == 'POST':
            response = urequests.post(config.AWS_API_URL, headers=headers, data=payload)
        elif http_method == 'PUT':
            response = urequests.put(config.AWS_API_URL, headers=headers, data=payload)
        elif http_method == 'DELETE':
            response = urequests.delete(config.AWS_API_URL, headers=headers)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported HTTP method: {http_method}")
        
        if response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code >= 400:
            print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Request failed: {e}")
        return

    response_json = json.loads(response.text)

    # Use this troubleshooting AWS. Get the message and any error from the response
    message = response_json.get('message')
    error = response_json.get('error')

    print("================================")
    print("Response")
    print("================================")
    if message is not None:
        message = message.replace("'", "") # Remove single quotes to make comparison easier
        print(f"Message: {message}")
    if error is not None:
        print(f"Error: {error}")

    print(response.text)
    # print(json.dumps(response_json))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**credentials.py**

```
# AWS Access Key
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "your AWS key here"

# AWS Secret Access Key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "your AWS secret key here"
```

**config.py**

```
import re

def parse_url(url):
    pattern = '^(https?):\\/\\/([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\?]*)(\\?(.*))?'
    match = re.match(pattern, url)

    if match is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid URL: {url}")

    protocol = match.group(1)
    host = match.group(2)
    uri = match.group(3)
    query_string = match.group(5) or ""

    return protocol, host, uri, query_string

# Specify the full API URL and the code will parse it into components.
AWS_API_URL = f"https://id-given-you-by-AWS.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/PATH?somekey=somevalue"

# Parse the URL into components
AWS_API_PROTOCOL, AWS_API_HOST, AWS_API_URI, AWS_API_QUERYSTRING = parse_url(AWS_API_URL)

host_parts = AWS_API_HOST.split('.')
AWS_API_ID = host_parts[0]
AWS_API_SERVICE = host_parts[1]
AWS_API_REGION = host_parts[2]
```

Hope that helps and best wishes to you.